# History of updated rows

Tags: sqlite

Imagine we have a CRUD application in Python and are using SQLite.
Let's say we have in SQLite a table called CUSTOMERS:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS
(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
NAME TEXT
PHONENUMBER TEXT);
```

Everytime we update something we want to be able to look back to get the previous data. Let's say we do:

```
UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET PHONENUMBER = "1065165" WHERE ID = 1;
```

Now I want to be able to get the old PHONENUMBER for ID = 1 or even the whole PHONENUMBER history of that single CUSTOMER ID.

How would I implement that? Does SQLite have native support for such a functionality or do I need to do it with an extra table (with CUSTOMER ID as Foreign Key) like "CUSTOMER_UPDATES" (DATE, FIELD, OLD_VARIABLE)?

Comment: Related and possibly helpful: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/156220/143380